# Trouble in a program to convert between currencies in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison

I've made a simple program in C++ to convert between currencies, as part of a lesson. It asks for a numerical value and then a letter (y, e or p) to represent one of the supported currencies. When using 'y' or 'p' you can input the numerical value and character together or separated by a space (ie: "100y" or "100 y") and it'll work fine. However, for the letter 'e' only, if I enter both together, it doesn't recognize as a valid input. Does anyone have any idea why?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
using namespace std;
constexpr double yen_to_dollar = 0.0081;    // number of yens in a dollar
constexpr double euro_to_dollar = 1.09;     // number of euros in a dollar
constexpr double pound_to_dollar = 1.54;    // number of pounds in a dollar

double money = 0;                           // amount of money on target currency
char currency = 0;
cout << "Please enter a quantity followed by a currency (y, e or p): " << endl;
cin >> money >> currency;

if(currency == 'y')
    cout << money << "yen == " << yen_to_dollar*money << "dollars." << endl;
else if(currency == 'e')
    cout << money << "euros == " << money*euro_to_dollar << "dollars." << endl;
else if(currency == 'p')
    cout << money << "pounds == " << money*pound_to_dollar << "dollars." << endl;
else
    cout << "Sorry, currency " << currency << " not supported." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason is that `100y` is not the start of a valid number, but `100e` is - in scientific notation.

Comment: Do not use floating point numbers for currency. People get funny over the odd penny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter `100e10e` it works ok. `100e10` is a valid number in scientific notation. `100e` is not a valid number in scientific notation. It is not converted to `double` and `money` is assigned 0. Variable `currency` stays unchanged. That is why you get "Sorry, currency not supported" message. `e` belongs to a number in this case, because it fits scientific notation format.

You could assign 4 chars to every currency( _EUR for instance ) . It would solve the problem and be more user friendly.

Comment: or to swap currency id and value, e.g. `e100`, it's quite popular notation anyway, e.g. $5, £3

Comment: When I enter '100e' it gives me the "Sorry, currency not supported" message.

Shouldn't it wait for me to enter a value for the 'currency' variable?